# Does $\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{x\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dx$ have a closed form?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{x\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dx$$

Does it have a closed solution? [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%5Cfrac%7Bxcos%20x%7D%7B1%2B2cos%20x%7Ddx%20from%200%20to%20%5Cpi%2F6) outputs this result.

Comment: https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=xcosx%2F%281%2B2cosx%29&lbound=0&ubound=pi%2F6

Comment: $1+2 cos(x)=2 cos^2(x/2)$

$\int \frac{x cos(x)}{1+2cos(x)}dx=\int [x-1/2 x (tan(x/2))']dx$

Comment: Since when Definite Integrals don't have closed forms? If you consider indefinite integral then I will say, Yes, it does **not** have a closed form.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%5Cfrac%7Bxcos+x%7D%7B1%2B2cos+x%7Ddx

Comment: I mean that whether the  definite Integral has an exact result expressing by elementary functional values or not. @SoumalyaPramanik

Comment: Mathematica says:`1/864 ((6 + 11 I Sqrt[3]) \[Pi]^2 + 
   8 Sqrt[3] \[Pi] Log[-10 + 6 Sqrt[3]] - 
   144 Sqrt[
    3] (Catalan - 
      I (PolyLog[2, -(-1)^(1/3)] - PolyLog[2, (-1)^(2/3)] + 
         PolyLog[2, (-1)^(5/6)])))`

Comment: You can use IBP to write the integral as $$\frac\pi6\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{\cos t}{1+2\cos t}dt-\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_0^{t}\frac{\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dxdt$$

Answer (score 1):

**(Basically) Complete Answer**

We define 
$$f(t)=\int_0^t \frac{\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dx$$
Then from integration by parts,
$$J=\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{x\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dx=\frac{\pi}{6}f\left(\frac\pi6\right)-\int_0^{\pi/6}f(t)dt\, .$$
First, I will find a closed form for $f(t)$, then I will proceed with $\int_0^{\pi/6}f(t)dt$.

---

We see that 
$$f(t)=\frac12\int_0^{t}\frac{-1+1+2\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dx=\frac{t}{2}-\frac12\int_0^{t}\frac{dx}{1+2\cos x}$$
In the remaining integral, we use [$u=\tan(x/2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) to get 
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^t\frac{dx}{1+2\cos x}&=2\int_0^{\tan(t/2)}\frac1{1+2\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\frac{du}{1+u^2}\\
&=2\int_0^{\tan(t/2)}\frac{du}{3-u^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\tan(t/2)}\frac{du}{1-u^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\left[\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac{t}2\right].
\end{align}$$
So 
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\left[\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac{t}2\right].$$
This gives 
$$\begin{align}
J&=\frac{\pi^2}{72}+\frac\pi{12\sqrt3}\ln(\sqrt{3}-1)-\int_0^{\pi/6}\left[\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac{t}2\right)\right]dt\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{144}+\frac\pi{12\sqrt3}\ln(\sqrt3-1)+\frac1{\sqrt3}\int_0^{\pi/6}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac{t}2\right)dt
\end{align}$$

---

The next integral is 
$$P=\int_0^{\pi/6}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac{t}2\right)dt.$$
Set $x=\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac{t}{2}$ to get 
$$P=2\sqrt3\int_0^{\frac2{\sqrt3}-1}\frac{\tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+3x^2}dx$$
Then recall that for $|z|<1$,
$$\tanh^{-1}(z)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
So 
$$P=2\sqrt3\sum_{n\geq0}\frac1{2n+1}\int_0^{\frac2{\sqrt3}-1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{3x^2+1}dx.$$
So we define
$$\begin{align}
j_n&=2\int_0^{\frac2{\sqrt3}-1}\frac{x^{2n}}{3x^2+1}xdx\\
&=\int_0^{7/3-4/\sqrt3}\frac{x^n}{3x+1}dx\\
&=\frac1{3^{n+1}}\int_1^{8-4\sqrt3}\frac{(x-1)^n}{x}dx.
\end{align}$$
Then we notice that $j_0=\frac13\ln(8-4\sqrt3)$ so that we can proceed for $n\geq1$ with the binomial theorem:
$$\begin{align}
j_n&=\frac1{3^{n+1}}\int_1^{8-4\sqrt3}\frac{(x-1)^n}{x}dx\\
&=\frac1{3^{n+1}}\int_1^{8-4\sqrt3}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}x^kdx\\
&=\frac1{3^{n+1}}\int_1^{8-4\sqrt3}\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{x}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}x^{k-1}\right]dx\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}\ln(8-4\sqrt3)+\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}\int_1^{8-4\sqrt3}x^{k-1}dx\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}\ln(8-4\sqrt3)+\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k}{n\choose k}\left[(8-4\sqrt3)^k-1\right].
\end{align}$$
So 
$$\begin{align}
P&=\sqrt{3}\left[j_0+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{j_n}{2n+1}\right]\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt3}\ln a+\frac1{\sqrt3}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{3^n(2n+1)}\left[(-1)^n\ln a+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k}{n\choose k}(a^k-1)\right]\\
&=\frac{\ln a}{\sqrt3}\left(1+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}\right)+\frac1{\sqrt3}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}{n\choose k}(a^k-1)\\
&=\frac\pi6\ln a+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}S(a)
\end{align}$$
Where $a=8-4\sqrt3$ and $$S(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}{n\choose k}(x^k-1).$$
Note that we used $$1+\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}=\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}$$
which comes from 
$$\tan^{-1}(z)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}\qquad |z|\leq1.$$

> Anyway, we combine results (and do a little algebra with the $\ln$ terms) to get
>   $$J=\frac{\pi^2}{144}+\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}\ln\left(4\sqrt{11\sqrt3-19}\right)+\frac13 S(8-4\sqrt3).$$
>   I will update my answer once I figure out how to compute $S(x)$.

**Update:** See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3244970/583016) for a way to find a closed form for $S(q)$ involving [$\mathrm{Li}_2(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function).

Answer (score 0):

Because...

$$\int \frac{x\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dx=\int_0^x \frac{t\cos t}{1+2\cos t}dt$$

...the definite integral...

$$\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{x\cos x}{1+2\cos x}dx$$

...may be regarded as the *value* of the function...

$$f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{t\cos t}{1+2\cos t}dt$$

...at $x=\pi/6$.

The function $f$ thus described is clearly *Liouvillian*, but this does **not** guarantee that it is *elementary*. As far as I'm aware, the only guaranteed way to show that a function defined via integral is elementary is to evaluate the integral. In this case $f(x)$ (according to WA) is expressed in terms of the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html), which is **not** an elementary function. So, if you wish to express the definite integral as $f(\pi/6)$ then no, there is no 'closed' form.